# Yellow in Shadows

Tags: adobe-photoshop

The image attached has some yellow fringing on and under the arm near the shadows.
The yellow only appears when I open the image in PS (left). When opening it elsewhere it is not there.
Any ideas on what is causing this and Is there any way to clean this up?

[image]

Comment: The psd is 16bpp, so the color is simulated (assuming a "regular" RGB monitor) which could explain the banding (large subtle transitions are represented by a larger range of number values that must be binned or quantized to a much smaller range of number values). It is also unclear if the right-hand photo has the same pixel dimensions: zooming out on the left one may exaggerate the color simulation problem.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, but only guesses are possible without examining your system, Photoshop color settings and work procedure how these images are made. Obviously they are the same shot, but PSD and JPG? Why difference? Have they got different treatments?

If we assume there's no intentional adjustments in PSD, there still can be different color management than in Win Photo Viewer.  Microsoft can have succeeded better this time, because it's very easy to have wrong color settings in Photoshop. In the past Microsoft attempted nothing, but in Windows 10 they do.

What they do? I have red that if there's a proper display color profile installed, Photo Viewer uses it. Unfortunately I haven't seen any data of does MS in addition try to "enhance Win experience" by guessing some fixes. In this case there's a genius in Microsoft if we assume PS shows the truth and Win has fixed the image shown in Photo Viewer.

The shadow area in PSD is so bad that I suspect wrong color management or there's some adjustment applied only to the PSD. There shadow areas seem like they have got color saturation boost.  Then there's gradient banding like somebody has tried to lighten the darkness for ex. with Curves. With it one gets easily the saturation boost as an unwanted bonus, when the tool increases also differences between R,G and B values. Unfortunately 8 bits/color/pixel isn't enough for lightening very dark areas, adjustments this heavy should be done for RAW photo.

Many people use smartphone cameras or full automatic pocket cameras. They are handy and in good light the results can be excellent. But if there's non-uniform or generally low light, the situation changes. Pocket and smartphone cameras start heavy processing effort to bring out something to watch but no software can guess what the darkness exactly hides and something like the dark areas in your PSD example can be resulted with no own adjustments. Clever software can in theory guess "that's human skin" and copy the color from well lit areas to too dark areas. That can happen in a clever photo viewer or even in the camera, when something like "hyper autofix portrait master mode" is in use.

My suggestions for taking photos:

1) have enough light, use a reflector or a lamp to avoid black shadows

2) be sure that you do not have 2 totally different colored lights. It's far too easy have for ex. daylight from a window on some areas in the image and some yellowish light from lamps in those areas where the daylight does not enter. The camera is in impossible situation, it has no possiblity to decide the colors in a pleasant way. Something is unavoidably too blue or too yellow.

3) Take important photos in RAW mode and learn how to "develop" 
 them to JPGs

**Fixing your current photo:** Check, if you can save it as it's shown in Win Photo Viewer. I haven't it so I cannot check it.

The easiest thing to try for your PSD version is to reduce the color. As written above there's a saturation boost especially in shadows, it's like like "add vibrancy" has been done in some phase, maybe in camera's automatic image enhancement or someone has used Photoshop's functions. That has lifted the saturation of low saturation areas to something untolerable. The baby seems to have a couple of burn injuries or bedsores in the darkest shadows.

The image has general yellowish cast probably due mixed light and that has got a boost where  the yellowish light is prominent. The next screenshot shows what can be achieved by reducing the vibrancy:

[image]

Removing the yellowish cast made it a little better:

[image]

The cast can be removed by opening the image as camera raw and pointing a grey point with the picker. I used a paid filter named "Color Washer"

There's still some greyish dirt-like areas which typically are resulted when one tries to fix too dark JPGs. Low resolution cannot keep smooth gradients. Before fixing the white balance (=removing the yellowish cast) they were yellow, but now we see them as grey.

The most disturbing borders can be fixed with the manual blur tool. Alternatively one can make a blurred version of the image and with a layer mask make it visible in the wanted places.

Here the blurred version has got Gaussian blur with radius = 3 px.

[image]